# How to make a grouped histogram with normal distributions with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, normal-distribution

When I tried to make some grouped histograms with base R and ggplot, I have found a different solution. Can someone help me to find the problem. I guess it is something with the y -axis.

First I created some subsets

```
Immature2=subset(dataHistogram2, Sex=='I')
Female2=subset(dataHistogram2, Sex=='F')
Male2=subset(dataHistogram2, Sex=='M')
```

**With base R**

```
hist(Immature2$Diameter, prob=TRUE ,breaks= seq(55,125, by=5), ylim=c(0,0.05), xlim=c(55,125), col=rgb(0,1,0,1/2), main="", xlab= "Diameter", ylab="Densiteit")
hist(Female2$Diameter, prob=TRUE, add=TRUE, breaks= seq(55,125, by=5), col=rgb(1,0,0,1/2))
hist(Male2$Diameter, prob= T,breaks=seq(55,125, by=5), add=T, col=rgb(0,0,1,1/2))
x=seq(55,125,0.01)
curveImmature2<-curve(dnorm(x,mean=mean(Immature2$Diam), sd=sd(Immature2$Diam)), add= TRUE, col=rgb(0,1,0,1/2), lwd=2)
curveFemale2 <- curve(dnorm(x,mean=mean(Female2$Diam), sd=sd(Female2$Diam)), add= TRUE, col= rgb(1,0,0,1/2), lwd=2)
curveMale2 <- curve(dnorm(x, mean=mean(Male2$Diam), sd=sd(Male2$Diam)), add= TRUE, col=rgb(0,0,1,1/2), lwd=2)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5skzr.png)

**With ggplot**

```
ggplot(dataHistogram2, aes(x=Diameter))+ geom_histogram(binwidth=5, aes(y=..density.., colour=Sex, fill= Sex), position="identity", alpha=0.5)+xlim(55,125)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMc6O.png)

So my questions: 
*How does it come that my bars in my ggplot are different from base R? 
*How can I plot my different subsets in an normal distribution on the histogram on ggplot2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a normal plot can be added with `+ stat_function(fun=dnorm, colour = "red", args=list(mean=mean(Immature2$Diam), sd=sd(Immature2$Diam)))`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response! It worked out! I still have a question why my two graphs have a different height of bars (you can see it in the pictures above e.g. blue bars( male) plummet at 115 if I used ggplot)

Comment: you could accept the answer. As for your question. It also happened to me before and I believe it's probably due to the density estimation (http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/stats/density). Yes, the blue bar plummet ~ 115 but the bars next to 115 are also a bit higher.